# What is int[] arr[] mean in Java?

Tags: java, arrays

I know that I can declare array that ways:

```
int[] arr1;      // one-dimensional array                                                                                     
int arr2[];      // one-dimensional array (declared using C-style)            
int[][] arr3;    // two-dimensional array    
int arr4[][];    // two-dimensional array (declared using C-style)            
int[] arr5[];    // - ? (possibly two-dimensional array)                                                                   
int[][] arr6[];  // - ? (possibly three-dimensional array)                                     
int[] arr7[][];  // - ? (possibly three-dimensional array)
```

Comment: yes, yes and yes. Just check it in your IDE of choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`int[] arr[]` is the c-style of declaration and is equivalent to `int[][] arr`;